# How to convert pytorch code that uses SqueezeNet pretrained model to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

i have the following pytorch code :

```
model = models.squeezenet1_1(pretrained=True)

num_classes = 2
model.classifier = nn.Sequential (
    nn.Dropout(0.1),
    nn.Conv2d(512, num_classes, kernel_size= (1,1), stride= (1,1)),
    nn.ReLU(), 
    nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size= 13, stride= 1, padding= 0)
    )
model.num_classes = num_classes
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

and id like to do convert this code into tensorflow as i need to use tensorflow and not pytorch. I've searched up some things and couldn't quite understand how to do it.

I have been able to get a pretrained SqueezeNet model thanks to the keras_squeezenet package (although it causes some future deprecation warnings with numpy when i load the model) , but then how can i change the Classifier , optimizer and number of classes for the model that i loaded like i did in pytorch ?

Im using tensorflow 1.14.0 and keras 2.3.1   (for some reason i couldn't get to launch tensorflow 2)

Also im only using the CPU because of session rights

EDIT thanks to @Albert :

Right now i have i simply have loaded the model from the package i took from https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet , and i did setup my different Image Folders  that i will use :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('path to my training', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32)
# load and iterate validation dataset
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('path to my validation', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32)
# load and iterate test dataset
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('path to my test', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32)

model = SqueezeNet(weights='imagenet')
```

I have found you must use model.compile to specify optimizer and loss with keras so i think it might look something like this , correct me if i am wrong :

```
model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If it is correct then i simply need to do

```
model.classifier = nn.Sequential (
    nn.Dropout(0.1),
    nn.Conv2d(512, num_classes, kernel_size= (1,1), stride= (1,1)),
    nn.ReLU(), 
    nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size= 13, stride= 1, padding= 0)
    )
model.num_classes = num_classes
```

in tenserflow/keras ; how can i do that ?

Comment: You should maybe show your current TF code as well, and link to what keras_squeezenet package you mean (I don't know it). You should maybe also ask somewhat more specific (separate) questions. E.g. like "I have this TF code: ..., how do I change the optimizer to Adam?".

Comment: @Albert Hello , thank you for your comment i did Edit my post and think i am heading the right way , do you have any tips from where i am now ? thank you !

Comment: As I see [from the code](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet/blob/4fb9cb7510ea0315303090edbc1bd97c2916af81/keras_squeezenet/squeezenet.py#L44), wouldn't you simply call `SqueezeNet(..., classes=num_classes)`? I still don't quite understand where exactly the problem is. You posted some code. Does it work? Or what exactly does not work? (Do you get errors? Or sth is wrong? Please provide those information...)

Comment: From the code we see that the weights can only be used with 1000classes since SqueezeNet is pretrained on 1000. I want to do fine-tuning , so on pytorch i  change the model.classifier and the number of classes so that it works for my specific need with two classes and i still get the pretrained weights that speeds up my training. Here i would need to let the default classes(1000)to load then weights and then change it to 2 in the last layers , but when i check the layers in tensorflow the conv2d doesn't have (in channels, out channels)when declared like in pytorch , so i don't know what to do

Comment: Also right now my only error is on the "BinaryCrossEntropy" loss that i used in model.compile , i don't think i took the right crossentropy function i will check again in the Loss functions documentation , i need the same function as my CrossEntropyLoss in pytorch

Comment: You cannot change the num classes after you already created the model. You need to have the right number of classes **while** creating the model. You likely cannot load the weights like that then (because they would not match). What do you do about the weights which do not match? Throw them away? You could load individual weights. Or you could convert your checkpoint such that it is matching. If you want to do that, better ask specific (separate) questions about exactly that.